# Can I leave SOAPConnection open forever?

Tags: java, soap, connection

Can I make SOAPConnection open forever? That is not calling connection.close() after soap request.

Comment: stale TCP connections will be killed by routers

Comment: What requirement is driving you to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Q: Can I make SOAPConnection open forever?

A: In theory, yes.

In practice, your connection will become stale and useless the moment the other endpoint hangs up on you.

It isn't necessarily a bad strategy to:

a) open the connection initially and read whatever you need

b) simply leave the connection open

c) check for errors (which you need to do anyway)

d) close and re-open only when necessary (when an attempted read fails)

Just a thought...

Answer (score 0):

there may be memory issues and as pointed out by the other user stale soap connections will be killed by routers

Answer (score 0):

You can do whatever you want do, But the best practice is something especially IO connection if you don't need use it again please close/release it, a numerous resources in memory can absolutely leak your program or even break it down.

But I am not sure whether there have a permanent principle in SOAPConnection that make a automatic closure after fixed time.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about `SAAJ`?

The underlying TCP connection is usually cached for a specific amount of time.
Either the amount of time the server endpoint specified in the HTTP header or the amount of time JVM keeps it open.

So if the connection remains idle for too long it will be releashed.
I am not sure how long it will remain open though